# Using bookshelf.js to query JSON column in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a column in the `users` table of my Postgres dB table that is named `email_subscription_prefs`, which stores some some information in JSON format.  It has an array_length of 1.

**Sample Data:**
`[{"marketing":true,"transactional":true,"collaboration":true,"legal":true,"account":true}]`

**Issue:**
I am trying to use bookshelf.js ORM to query and search all records in this table based on the value of the `marketing` key, specifically when its valueis `true`.

Here is an edited snippet of my code showing what I'm trying to implement this query using bookshelf.js:

```
return new User()
   qb.where(function() {
     this.where('domicile', 'USA').orWhere('domicile', null)
   })
   qb.whereRaw('cast(email_subscription_prefs->>? as boolean) = ?', ['marketing', true])
   qb.limit(100)
  })
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong on qb.whereRaw statement where I'm trying to query the JSON column `email_subscription_prefs`?

The code returns nothing where there are several thousands records in the `users` table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an array of objects in sample data instead of single json object.

```
[
  {
    "marketing":true,
    "transactional":true,
    "collaboration":true,
    "legal":true,
    "account":true
  }
]
```

so looks like you are trying to refer `email_subscription_prefs->>'marketing'` which is not found from the array.

To fetch `marketing` attribute of the first item in the array you should do:

```
email_subscription_prefs->0->>'marketing'
```

If that is not the problem, then you would need to add some example data from your DB to be able to tell what is the problem. You current description doesn't describe the queried table well enough.

Comment: Thanks Mikael.  This makes a lot of sense; however, I ended up solving this specific problem/issue by converting the array into a single JSON object becasue in this case there is need for an array.  Your comment will definitely be helpful when I encounter the same issue for an array that must be an array.